# How to make a cross field validation with a custom message in vee-validate?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vee-validate

See [this](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/advanced/cross-field-validation.html#targeting-multiple-fields) document please.

In the example shown here, I need to show the `min` and `max` values in my message.

How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated answers

Those pages helped me out:

- [Target Fields Names](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/advanced/cross-field-validation.html#target-fields-names)
- [between rule](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/rules.html#between)
- [Rules object expression](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/advanced/rules-object-expression.html#supplying-arguments)
- [Messages as functions](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/basics.html#messages)

This is how you can achieve this by referencing the various inputs.

```html
<template>
  <ValidationObserver>
    <ValidationProvider
      :rules="{ required: true, between: { min: '@min', max: '@max' } }"
      v-slot="{ errors }"
    >
      <ValidationProvider
        rules="required"
        vid="min"
        v-slot="{ errors, message }"
      >
        <input type="number" v-model.number="minValue" />
        <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
        <div>message here: {{ message }}</div>
      </ValidationProvider>

      <input type="number" v-model.number="value" />
      <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>

      <ValidationProvider vid="max" rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
        <input type="number" v-model.number="maxValue" />
        <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
      </ValidationProvider>
    </ValidationProvider>
  </ValidationObserver>
</template>

<script>
import { extend } from "vee-validate";

extend("between", {
  params: ["min", "max"],
  validate(value, { min, max }) {
    return value >= min && value <= max;
  },
  message: (_, values) =>
    `This field value must be between ${values["_min_"]} and ${values["_max_"]}`,
});

export default {
  data: () => ({
    minValue: 0,
    value: 1,
    maxValue: 10,
  }),
};
</script>
```

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-forked-i2zrv?file=/src/Demo.vue:0-1188).

---

Not sure why referencing another field is not working so far: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/advanced/cross-field-validation.html#targeting-other-fields

You can achieve it simply by changing `rules="required|between:@min,@max"` into `rules="required|between:4,25"`.

Let me see if I can find the way of writing it by referencing another field!